# JS touchmove events that stop triggering.

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, touch

I have a webapp project I am working with a graphical chart that I want to respond to the touchstart and the touchmove events. I have the events bound to an element  that is overlaying the chart canvas element and for the most part everything is working as expected.

I am however, experiencing some behavior where the events eventually stop triggering. I am seeing this happen in at least two ways:

First case: It all appears to be a somewhat sporadic stopping (I can't narrow down exactly what it is that is going on right before they stop). Everything will work fine for a while but then eventually touch events just stop triggering.

Second case: When I update the app (which removes the bound element, reappends a new element to DOM, and then re-binds the new element with the same events). After this update I get exactly one single touchstar/touchmove to trigger. After that single firing no further touch events to trigger.

Here is the website I am working on: [mortgagevista.com](http://mortgagevista.com)

I can't for the life of me figure out what is going on. I have spent hours reading up on forums and SO and still can't seem to figure out what the issue is. Unfortunately I am even out of ideas on how to troubleshoot the problem. I have been using the emulator in the chrome dev tools reproduce the problem.

Does this issue sound familiar to anybody?  Any common issues or pitfalls with the touch events that I might be missing?  Any ideas on how to best go about troubleshooting this? (Sorry, I know this is a really vague question but I am out of ideas on even how to narrow down what is happening).

Answer (score 1):

Your events are not going to the right place. There is two possible reasons for this.

1. An incorrect element has focus.
2. An invisible overlay or something similar is not getting clicked as you expect.

Drill into these to issues and see if you can find the root cause.

Good luck.

Comment: Well, something of the sort does indeed seem to be the cause of the issue. As of yet I have no idea why I am loosing focus and I am still experiencing some unexpected behavior.  The super “hacky” quick fix I came up with is after each touch event I use jquery to focus on the first input element on the page then blur that element, everything seems to work as.  If I try to simply focus on the overlay element that should be receiving the events (or on body or document) it does not solve the issue.

Comment: More strangely, if I try using the Chrome dev tools “monitorEvents” function I can not reproduce the issue at all while the monitorEvents function is active...